# pandas replace values of a list column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

| ID | Feeback |
| --- | --- |
| T223 | [Good, Bad, Bad] |
| T334 | [Average,Good,Good] |

```
feedback_dict = {'Good':1, 'Average':2, 'Bad':3}
```

using this dictionary I have to replace Feedback column

| ID | Feeback |
| --- | --- |
| T223 | [1, 3, 3] |
| T334 | [2,1,1] |

I tried two way, but none worked, any help will be appreciated.

```
method1:    
df = df.assign(Feedback=[feedback_dict.get(i,i)  for i in list(df['Feedback'])])

method2:
df['Feedback'] = df['Feedback'].apply(lambda x : [feedback_dict.get(i,i)  for i in list(x)])
```

Comment: The original name of your column in your example is "Feeback", not "Feedback". Maybe that is why your code does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were pretty close to the solution.

What I did was:

```
data.replace({'Good': '1', 'Average': '2', 'Bad': '3'}, regex=True)
```

and obtain the result that you were looking:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yI4pE.png)

Comment: I contributed a different answer, but this is definitely the most elegant.

Comment: Agreed! this worked even if Feeback column is not a list. You also addressed the other problem with my feedback_dict dictionary, numbers should be encapsulated as strings to avoid errors. Then, we can do this --> data.replace(feedback_dict, regex=True)

Answer (score 1):

For me second solution working, but necessary convert strings to lists before:

```
import ast

df['Feedback'] = df['Feedback'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
#df['Feedback'] = df['Feedback'].str.strip('[]').str.split(',')
```

First solution working with nested dictionary:

```
df = df.assign(Feedback=[[feedback_dict.get(i,i) for i in x] for x in df['Feedback']])


df['Feedback'] = df['Feedback'].apply(lambda x : [feedback_dict.get(i,i)  for i in list(x)])
print (df)
     ID    Feedback
0  T223  [1, 3, 3]
1  T334  [2, 1, 1]
```

EDIT: If instead lists are missing values use `if-else` statement - non list values are replaced to empty lists:

```
print (df)
     ID             Feedback
0  T223       [Good,Bad,Bad]
1  T334  [Average,Good,Good]
2   NaN                  NaN


feedback_dict = {'Good':1, 'Average':2, 'Bad':3}
df = df.assign(Feedback=[[feedback_dict.get(i,i) for i in x] if isinstance(x, list) else [] 
                            for x in df['Feedback']])

print (df)
     ID   Feedback
0  T223  [1, 3, 3]
1  T334  [2, 1, 1]
2   NaN         []
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, I tried nested dict, but got this error TypeError: 'NAType' object is not iterable

Comment: @Arjun - Answer was EDITed.

Answer (score 1):

If your usecase is about as simple as this example, I wouldn't recommend this method. However, here's another option in case it makes other parts of your project easier.

1. [`df.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) your column (assuming it is a list and not text; otherwise convert it to a list first)
2. Perform the replacements with [`df.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)
3. Group the rows back together again with [`df.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`df.agg()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html)

For the example, it would look like this (assuming the variables have been declared like in your question):

```
df = df.explode('Feedback')
df['Feedback'] = df['Feedback'].replace(feedback_dict)
df = df.groupby('ID').agg(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l , L = [] , []  # two list for adding new values into them

for lst in df.Feeback: # call the lists in the Feeback column
    for i in last: #calling each element in each lists
        if i == 'Good': #if the element is Good then:
            l.append(feedback_dict['Good'])   #append the value 1 to the first created list
        if i == 'Average':  #if the element is Average then:
            l.append(feedback_dict['Average'])  #append the value 2 to the first created list
        if i == 'Bad':   #if the element is Bad then:
            l.append(feedback_dict['Bad']) #append the value 3 to the first created list
L.append(l[:3])  # we need to split half of the first list to add as a list to the second list and the other half as another list to the second list we created
L.append(l[3:])
df['Feeback'] = L  #at the end just put the values of the second created list as feedback column
```